# Publish array of int as string over MQTT on Arduino

Tags: arduino, esp32

This drives me nuts for hours now as newbie:

I have:

`int relayStates[] = {0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0};`

Later in my code I want to publish the states as char[] with PubSubClient MQTT as:

`00110100`

`client.publish(topic,<here char[]>);`

I tried al conversions I can think of but nothing works.
Can somebody help me?

Best regards,
Oscar

Comment: try to use the CStringBuilder from my StreamLib. the library is in Library manager and you can find an example how to use it in IDE Examples menu after installing the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets do it the manual way so you learn how to build strings from int arrays
Define a global char array sized big enough:

```
char textToSend [9] = {'\0'}; // takes 8 chars and a terminator
```

here we copy from `relayStates[]` and "convert" to char (could work for all single digits)

```
  textToSend [0] = '\0'; // we reset the char array
 for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
   if (relayStates[i] == 0) textToSend [i] = '0'; // SINGLE quote as it is a char
   if (relayStates[i] == 1) textToSend [i] = '1'; // SINGLE quote as it is a char
 }
 textToSend [8] = '\0'; // we terminate the char array
 client.publish(topic, textToSend); // we transfer the array content to MQTT
```

This method is transparent, memory efficient and can be used for stable production environments.
Improvements you could add:

- Getting the end value of the for loop from the int array size
- making it work with ints other than 0 and 1 - use a helper array to convert

  - `char numBuffer [9] = {'\0'}; // takes 8 chars and a terminator for converting ints`
  - `itoa(relayStates[i], numBuffer,10);  // converts an int to a base 10 dec char array`
  - `strcat(textToSend, numBuffer);`

Comment: Thank you!! Great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late question to this topic. I tried the solution to publish an array of ints (other than 0 and 1). But there is only one int written in the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
    digitalWrite(adressPins[j], bitRead(i, j));
    delayMicroseconds(50);
  }
  feuchteRoh[i] = analogRead(33);
}

for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
  trockenheit[i] = map(feuchteRoh[i], rohTief, rohHoch, 0, 100);
}

for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
  feuchtigkeit[i] = 100 - trockenheit[i];
  Serial.println(feuchtigkeit[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
  
 itoa(feuchtigkeit[i], numBuffer, 10);
}
Serial.println(numBuffer);


msg[0] = '\0';
strcat(msg, numBuffer);
msg[10] = '\0';
client.publish("ESP32/ Test", msg);
```

The names of the variables are in german, I hope this is not a problem.

Thank you for the help.